# Webview had to refresh a Website automaticly

Tags: android, webview, refresh

I am a beginner in Android Studio but I tried very hard to refresh the website but nothing worked. Is there maybe a simple code to solve my problem? please help !

public class Motordrehzahl_App extends Activity {

```
private WebView myWebView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_motordrehzahl__app);

    myWebView=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
    refresh();
```

`public void refresh()
    {
        while(true) {
            myWebView.clearView();
            myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
        }
    }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the method relaod(). 
It should do the job

```
    final WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);

    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl("http://stackoverflow.com/questions");


    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            webView.reload();
        }
    });
```

I hope it helps.